# Suppress standard Output

Tags: stdout

Here is my command in the shell script.   I want all the output to be redirected to a standard Log File. It does that fine except at when it does not find the *.txt files with a directory or sub directory, it writes the o/p to std output screen. How to suppress this and send it to the Log file.

```
TOTALFILES=`ls $SOURCEDIR/$SOURCESUBDIR/*.txt| wc -l` >> $WORKDIR/$LOGFNAME
```

Comment: You are likely see the standard *error* stream, not the standard *output* stream. See for example [What were the original reason(s) for adding a “standard error” which is separate from “standard output”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461267/what-were-the-original-reasons-for-adding-a-standard-error-which-is-separate)

Answer (score 0):

It **does not** "write the o/p to std output".  It writes it to `stderr`.  Also it won't write stdout to your file either.  When you use command substitution you are telling it to write stdout to the variable `TOTALFILES`.

If you want your output to go to both the variable and the file you will need to use `tee`:

```
totalfiles=$(ls "${sourcedir}/${sourcesubdir}/"*.txt | wc -l | tee "${workdir}/${logfname}")
```

However this also wont send stderr to your log file, to do that you could do:

```
totalfiles=$(ls "${sourcedir}/${sourcesubdir}/"*.txt 2>"${workdir}/${logfname}" | wc -l | tee "${workdir}/${logfname}")
```

stdin is fd0
stdout is fd1
stderr is fd2

To redirect stdout:

```
foo > /path/file
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
foo 1> /path/file
```

---

To redirect stderr:

```
foo 2> /path/file
```

---

To redirect both:

```
foo > /path/file 2>&1
```

> Note that the order of redirections is significant

Reading:  [3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)

---

With bash you can also shorten this using `&>` for example:

```
foo &> /path/file
```

(You should avoid uppercase variable names, you should also quote all your variables and use `$( ... )` instead of backticks.

Comment: TOTALFILES=`ls $SOURCEDIR/$SOURCESUBDIR/*.txt| wc -l` >> $WORKDIR/$LOGFNAME 2>&1 . THis is not working for me..

Comment: @veekay: Yes it should not work, you have not read my answer.

Comment: Also, it's generally better to use `set` with the globbing pattern and then `$#` to see how many names matched (with `nullglob` set in `bash`).

Comment: @Jesse_b I missed checking the initial response and it works fine.. what is the significance of NOT using uppercase variable names..